# How do I diagnose the programming interface to a MSP430 i2030 using launchpad?

Tags: msp430, launchpad

I have to use MSP430i2030 for a project and I tried burning code on it using MSP430G2553 launchpad. I tried burning a simple code on toggling the LED, however, the CCS complained that it could not find the chip, yet I could see the LED being toggled. But no matter what changes I make to the code, it keeps on toggling (even when i commented that part of the code). Below is the way in which I connected my chip to the launchpad.

Can anyone please suggest an appropriate way to connect the chip to the launchpad? How do I setup the interface correctly?
[image]

Also, as per Texas Instruments, this chip cannot be used with the launchpad, however, I have gone through some examples where people are able to use the unsupported micro-controllers as well.

Comment: Apparently, TI is right and those examples are wrong.

Comment: Could you suggest any other way apart from using MSP-TS430RHB32A(as per TI).

Comment: Without a schematic or a better picture, it's hard to tell exactly how your chip is hooked up, but if my interpretation is correct, your MSP430 has no ground connection.

Comment: yes, in the current image it is not connected to ground, however, I did connect the relevant pin (AVss) to ground, yet I am getting the same error.

Comment: Try adding a 47k pullup to the RST line as specced by TI and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Also, SBW needs DVss to function, so tie AVss and DVss to GND.

Comment: @Cheibriados Thanks for that, however, the only visible change is that the LED has stopped toggling and I am getting the same error on CCS.

Comment: Also tried with RST pull up as per this link: http://hackaday.com/2010/09/28/launchpad-not-limited-to-value-line-chips/. yet getting an error

Answer (score 1):

After repeated attempts to communicate with the chip using launchpad, I can finally say that it is not possible to use launchpad for programming MSP430i2030.